# Save accessToken to local storage using passport-facebook

Tags: node.js, passport-facebook, passport.js

I'm new to MEAN Stack, I'm having trouble saving passport-facebook accessToken to localStorage. How do I do this? Below is my setup.

```
 passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
        clientID: passport_config.facebook.clientID,
        clientSecret: passport_config.facebook.clientSecret,
        callbackURL: passport_config.facebook.callbackURL
      },
      function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        FBAccount.findOne({fbId : profile.id}, function(err, oldUser){
            if(oldUser){
                done(null,oldUser);
            }else{
                var newUser = new FBAccount({
                    fbId  : profile.id ,
                    name  : profile.displayName
                }).save(function(err,newUser){
                    if(err) throw err;
                    console.log(newUser);
                    done(null, newUser);
                });
            }
        });
      }
    ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var localStorage = require('localStorage')

localStorage.setItem('accessToken', accessToken);
FBAccount.findOne({ ....
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution. I added local storage and put your suggested code. But, when I view my local storage it was not there. I was able to console log my accessToken though.

Comment: Did you check using `localStorage.getItem('accessToken')` ?
It will be saved on Node server, not the browser.
But to handle session you should use **Redis**

Comment: I see, yeah I was able to see it now. Thanks. I might be asking to much but how do I set this to localstorage on the browser?

Comment: You can return the `accessToken` via `res`, then one HTML file, using js to save it to localstorage `localStorage.setItem('accessToken', accessToken)`

Comment: Oh I see, I'm not quite sure what you mean with via res but I'll  try to search on that.

Comment: Check out how to use Redis to handle session for express + passport [here](http://afshinm.name/redis-as-session-store-for-expressjs-passportjs)

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the additional knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add token in the cookies by some middleware like

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
   clientID: '566950043453498',
   clientSecret: '555022a61da40afc8ead59c6c26306ed',
   callbackURL: 'http://www.localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback'
}, function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    console.log("hello " + profile.displayName);
    done(null); 
 }
));

//Authentication
app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook'));

router.get('/auth/facebook/callback', passport.authenticate('facebook', {
    failureRedirect: '/login?failedSocial=facebook'
  }), auth.authCallback);
```

and in auth service

```
exports.authCallback = function (req, res) {
    res.res.cookie('token', JSON.stringify(req.user.token));
    res.redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: That's correct except instead of req.user.token it should be req.query.code